# triggering a callback function on completing all animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that can be iterated from 1 to 5 times (it's can be every time a different number)
and the loop looks like

```
/*
 * Loop over the intros, and show one by one.
 */
            for( var i = 1; i <= intros.length; i++ ) {

                // Introduce loop delays.
                (function(i){
                    setTimeout(function(){

                        $( intros[ i - 1] ).fadeOut(520, function() {

                            $( menu_items[ i - 1] ).removeClass("active");

                            if( i <= intros.length ) {
                                $( intros[ i ] ).delay(250).fadeIn("slow");
                                $( menu_items[ i ] ).addClass("active")
                            }
                        });

                    }, 6000*i);
                }(i));
            }
```

Now I need to trigger a callback function after completing these all animations. can it be soled with Deffered object, $.when or any other solution?

Comment: from where I see it it could be done different ways. Did you try something yet ?

Comment: I am trying to use $.when but some how working not properly. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not. Maybe someoe else can help too, but you need to edit your question and show what you've tried preferably IN THE QUESTION, not in the comments :-)